# How to create admin and superadmin in vb.net using login controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to create admin and superadmin in vb.net using asp:login controls ?

i use create user wizard and login to perform this action

Super admin can delete any admin .... but admin does not have any rights to delete anything from website...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Web Site Administration Tool

The Web Site Administration Tool is available from within Visual Studio 2008.
Link:
http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3569166/Configuring-Your-ASPNET-20-Site.htm